# Optimize a JQuery For Each Loop for large lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, each

I have a `unordered list` which has values upto `350`. Now out of `350`, I want to set a `css` property for `6` values of the `list`. Issue is my `each` loop becomes very slow since i have to iterate through each and every `value`. Is there any way or logic to optimize the below each loop. Below code.

```
$('ul.list.available li').each(function()
{
  if($(this)[0].innerText == 'Cat' || $(this)[0].innerText == 'Dog' || $(this)[0].innerText == 'Buffalo' ||
          $(this)[0].innerText == 'Ant' || $(this)[0].innerText == 'Rat' || $(this)[0].innerText == 'Mice' )
  {
         $(this)[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Comment: you could add a counter to exit the each after you found the 6 matches

Comment: You should store the value of $(this)[0].innerText in a variable so you do not have to traverse the DOM 6 times.

Comment: Please edit the question for the first/last 6 or some other 6, which is it?  This is important information on a performance related question

Comment: I am sorry @MarkSchultheiss values are dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an Array to populate your words. Than you could use jQuery's `.filter()` Method and JavaScript's `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const words = ["Cat", "Dog", "Mice"]; // <<< populate this one!
$('ul.list.available li').filter((i, el) => words.includes(el.textContent)).hide();
```

```html
<ul class="list available">
  <li>Bicycle</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Boat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mice</li>
  <li>Computer</li>
</ul>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

[jQuery filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
[MDN Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Wowwww. Awesome Bro... Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to another answer but allows you to send how many (at then END with the `slice()`) and the array to a function and I add a class - which might include hiding stuff.  So, to hide them all just pass 0 to `hideSome(0, testfilters);`.  You could also modify this to hide all BUT the last 6, your question and comments made your intent somewhat variable/unclear thus this answer.

```js
function hideSome(howMany = 6, testArr) {
  let things = $('ul.list.available').find('li');
  let filteredThings = things.filter(function(index, element) {
   return testArr.includes(element.innerText);
  });
  filteredThings
    .slice(-howMany)
    .addClass("what-to");
}
let testfilters = ["Cat", "Dog", "Buffalo", "Ant", "Mice", "Rat"];

hideSome(6, testfilters);
```

```css
.what-to {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
.found{color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list available">
  <li>I am 0</li>
  <li>I am 1</li>
  <li>Rat</li>
  <li>rat</li>
  <li>I am 4</li>
  <li>Mice</li>
  <li>I am 6</li>
  <li>Ant</li>
  <li>I am 8</li>
  <li>mice</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Chicken</li>
  <li>Hog</li>
  <li>I am 13</li>
  <li>Ant</li>
  <li>Pant</li>
  <li>Mice</li>
  <li>Buffalo</li>
  <li>Rat</li>
  <li>The end</li>
</ul>
<div id="indicator"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `$` function 7 times, when one will do. Also, setting a counter to indicate when 6 have been hidden will save lots of iteration too:

```
var counter = 0;

$('ul.list.available li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      text  = $this[0].innerText;

  if( text == 'Cat' || text == 'Dog' || text == 'Buffalo' || text == 'Ant' || text == 'Rat' || text == 'Mice' )
  {
    $this[0].style.display = 'none';
    counter++;
  } 

  if( counter == 6 )
  {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: BenM - Thank you for your help. My 6 values are at the bottom of the list. I mean will this work?

Comment: Assuming that's the only instance of them in the list, yes. If there are earlier instances, it will not hide the last ones. If you know where they are in the list, why not just use the `gt()` selector?

Comment: Sorry @BenM . The values are dynamic based on conditions. I will try your solution. THank you again